# Search after Kubernetes projects as test subjects

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I'm writing my master thesis about best practices for Kubernetes development, and then implement a prototype to perform statical analysis on Kubernetes manifests to check whether the best practices are adhered to.
Now I'm looking for projects which are "production-ready", so in a state where they already had time to enforce best practices and not in the state "I just want to get things running for now".
I'm thankful for any hint to interesting projects, that I can use as test subjects for my evaluation part in the future.
Also if you have read any interesting article or scientific paper that I should not have missed, I'm looking forward to input like that as well.
Thank you all
Have a great day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very good resource for kubernetes project is the [oficial](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable) helm chart repository.

In [this](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable) link you can see a list of all stable charts and also the date of the last commit.

HELM is a package manager for kubernetes, similar idea to apt on debian, yum for redhat and so one.

[Here](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/) you can find the helm install guide.

After installing, you have to add the repository:

```
$ helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
$ helm repo update
```

Inside every project folder you have the README.md with all information about the project and how to install it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I'll mainly focus on projects using helm then. Seems to become the standard when working with Kubernetes

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps your master thesis project is already implemented by [conftest](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/conftest) - a tool which helps you write tests against structured configuration data.

For example, the following rule will prevent running containers as root

```
deny[msg] {
  input.kind = "Deployment"
  not input.spec.template.spec.securityContext.runAsNonRoot = true
  msg = "Containers must not run as root"
}
```

Check some other [kubernetes examples](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/conftest/tree/master/examples/kubernetes).

Comment: other tools https://learnk8s.io/validating-kubernetes-yaml

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Conftest is a great tip. I'll have a deeper look into it.